# Change img src using mutationObserver without recursion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mutation-observers

I'm trying to change the source of an image using `mutationObserver`, to check the `document.body` for dynamically created elements, then update them, accordingly.

I suspect that since I'm using `{attributes: true, subtree: true}`, the callback fires each time I try to update the `src`, causing the page to become unresponsive.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I thought my `forEach` was the issue, but even without it, the problem persists. I even tried to return the value from the `mutationObserver` to use inside a function, but it just comes back `undefined` unless I choose to instead `console.log`.

Code below:

```
var target = document.body;
config = {attributes: true, subtree: true}

var makeObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){

        if (mutation.target.tagName === 'IMG'){
            mutation.target.src = "http://example.com/some_img.jpg";        
            console.log(mutation.target);
        }
    });
});

(function(){
    makeObserver.observe(target, config);   
})();
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if (mutation.target.tagName === 'IMG' && mutation.target.src !== newURL){` ? But using an MutationObserver here sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need it ? Don't you have the control over the code which does modify your DOM ? If so, throw your code away, it's dangerous ; otherwise, tell your code to also do your img updates when needed.

Comment: @Kaiido That worked, thank you! It's funny, I thought to compare `!==` at some point, but I didn't think that was the issue. I'm writing an extension, so I don't have any control over the way/when content is loaded, and don't want it to break on pages with infinite scroll, or that load content after `onDOMready`.